# Initializing a private static member variable in the cpp file. error: member is private

Tags: c++, static, initialization, private

Here is a simple example illustrating my problem.

IDGenerator.hpp

```
#ifndef IDGENERATOR_HPP_
#define IDGENERATOR_HPP_

class IDGenerator {

   private:
      static int s_nNextID;

      // make the IDGenerator class a static class with a private default constructor
      IDGenerator();

   public:
      static int GetNextID();

};

#endif
```

IDGenerator.cpp

```
#include "IDGenerator.hpp"

// initialize the static id
int IDGenerator::s_nNextID(1);

int GetNextID()
{
   return IDGenerator::s_nNextID++;
}
```

I have tried initializing both explicitly (int IDGenerator::s_nNextID = 1;) and implicitly as shown.
Here is the compile command and the error

```
g++ -c IDGenerator.cpp
IDGenerator.cpp: In function ‘int GetNextID()’:
IDGenerator.cpp:11:5: error: ‘int IDGenerator::s_nNextID’ is private
 int IDGenerator::s_nNextID(1);
     ^
IDGenerator.cpp:15:22: error: within this context
  return IDGenerator::s_nNextID++;
```

I have also tried to compile with -Wall and std=gnu++11. Same error

Comment: What's the int doing in your IDGenerator.cpp?

Comment: @user3528438 It's being defined and initialised there, absolutely correctly. It's a *static* member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error isn't about the initialization. It just points to the initialization as the point where s_nNextID comes from.

The real error is on line 15, where you access s_nNextID from a normal global function, because you forgot the `IDGenerator::` in the definition head of `GetNextID`.

Answer (score 0):

s_nNextID is private so you can't just access it like this. You need to make GetNextID a member of the class IDGenerator.